# Memory not releasing when Replacescene in cocos2d-x 3.2

Tags: memory-management, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am developing game in cocos2d-x 3.2 and my app memory increase with game progresses & it seems resources memory not releasing while scene replacing in cocos2d-x 3.2 , please help

Comment: can you please share some Code

Comment: Code would make helping you out a lot easier, but check out this previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237347/cocos2d-project-with-many-scenes-does-not-release-memory-properly) .

Comment: I solve most of my issues by making auto-release every those object which was initialized using new operator , plus at every scene transitions i remove every objects of that scene by pushing them in array .. that way it worked .. i don't think its proper way to release memory but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Director::getInstance()->purgeCachedData();
```

to release those unused resources in the TextureCache, SpriteFrameCache, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing some code this will be hard to answer correctly, but I'm going to venture a guess or two. Hopefully this'll help.

A common mistake is not using the `::create()` functions all `Node` related classes have by default. Using `::create()` makes sure a `Ref` is used, meaning the object will be reference counted, and the memory pretty much automatically freed up again after replacing the scene. So if you use `new Scene()` somewhere in your code (and you don't release it in the destructor) instead of `Scene::create()` you'll have a memory leak right there.

The same goes for `Sprite`, `Node`, `Action`, basically anything. Always use their related `::create()` static function. If you have inherited from any of these classes, you can easily create your own `create()` method by placing `CREATE_FUNC(Player)` in the class definition, in the header. In this case `Player` being the name of the class you created that extends an existing class, like `Node` or `Sprite`.